# How may I add text into the citation basket?

Tags: bibliographies, citing

By using `\cite{}` command, I know how to add a reference. For example, by using code

```
\cite{xxx}, Lemma 1
```

I have the following output

[image]

However, now I want to achieve the following:

[image]

i.e., put some text inside the basket generated by `\cite{}` command.

How may I do this? Moreover, for some reasons, my template does not allow me to use `natbib` package...

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you tried `\cite[Lemma~1]{xxx}`?